# How to obtain "time difference" between 2 consecutive records?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given that i have a dataset as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt = {
    "facility":["Ann Arbor","Ann Arbor","Detriot","Detriot","Detriot"],
    "patient_ID":[4388,4388,9086,9086,9086],
    "year":[2004,2007,2007,2008,2011],
    "month":[8,9,9,6,2],
    "Nr_Small":[0,0,5,12,10],
    "Nr_Medium":[3,1,1,4,3],
    "Nr_Large":[2,0,0,0,0]
}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dt)
dt.head()
```

For each group of users (consider it as `groupby patient_ID` ), I wish to **obtain the the difference between** `year` and `month` **between each 2 consecutive rows.** Here is my code:

```
patients = dt['patient_ID'].unique()


for patient in patients:
    print(patient)
    patientDT = dt[ dt.patient_ID == patient] # Get group of records for each paitent
    patientDT['NumberOfVisits'] = np.shape(patientDT)[0] # Add number of records for each paitent as a new column     

    patientDT.sort_values(['year', 'month'], ascending=[True, True],inplace=True) # sort by year and month
    patientDT = addPeriodBetween2Visits(patientDT)

    print(patientDT)

    print("------------------------------")
```

and then the method which must obtain the difference is `addPeriodBetween2Visits` :

```
def addPeriodBetween2Visits(patientDT):

    for i in range(0,np.shape(patientDT)[0]):

        if(i == 0):
            patientDT['PeriodBetween2Visits'] = 0
        else:
            lastVisit = patientDT.loc[i-1,'year']*12 + patientDT.loc[i-1,'month']
            recentVisit = patientDT.loc[i,'year']*12 + patientDT.loc[i,'month']
            patientDT.loc[i,'PeriodBetween2Visits'] = recentVisit - lastVisit


    return patientDT
```

Unfortunately, it is failing, but the error is not clear for me. Here is the error log in **jupyter notebook**:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-eda12d36a355> in <module>
      8 
      9     patientDT.sort_values(['year', 'month'], ascending=[True, True],inplace=True)
---> 10     patientDT = addPeriodBetween2Visits(patientDT)
     11 
     12     print(patientDT)

<ipython-input-2-c8b1e6851452> in addPeriodBetween2Visits(patientDT)
      7         else:
      8             #print(patientDT.loc[i-1,'year'])
----> 9             lastVisit = patientDT.loc[i-1,'year']*12 + patientDT.loc[i-1,'month']
     10             recentVisit = patientDT.loc[i,'year']*12 + patientDT.loc[i,'month']
     11             patientDT.loc[i,'PeriodBetween2Visits'] = recentVisit - lastVisit

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1492             except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1493                 pass
-> 1494             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1495         else:
   1496             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    866     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
    867         try:
--> 868             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
    869         except IndexingError:
    870             pass

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    986         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
    987             if is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 988                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    989 
    990                 # we have yielded a scalar ?

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1911         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1912         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1913         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1914 
   1915 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    139             raise IndexingError('no slices here, handle elsewhere')
    140 
--> 141         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    142 
    143     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3583                                                       drop_level=drop_level)
   3584         else:
-> 3585             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3586 
   3587             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Here is the favorit output:

[image]

***I will be thankful, if you specifically tell me why my code is not working.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For counts use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with `Series`, so grouping by column `dt['patient_ID']`, then replace missing values and conver to integers:

```
dt['NumberOfVisits'] = dt['patient_ID'].map(dt['patient_ID'].value_counts())

dt["PeriodBetween2Visits"] = (dt["year"].mul(12)
                                        .add(dt["month"])
                                        .groupby(dt['patient_ID'])
                                        .diff()
                                        .fillna(0)
                                        .astype(int))


print (dt)
    facility  patient_ID  year  month  Nr_Small  Nr_Medium  Nr_Large  \
0  Ann Arbor        4388  2004      8         0          3         2   
1  Ann Arbor        4388  2007      9         0          1         0   
2    Detriot        9086  2007      9         5          1         0   
3    Detriot        9086  2008      6        12          4         0   
4    Detriot        9086  2011      2        10          3         0   

   NumberOfVisits  PeriodBetween2Visits  
0               2                     0  
1               2                    37  
2               3                     0  
3               3                     9  
4               3                    32
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```py
dt["diff"]=dt["year"].mul(12).add(dt["month"])
dt['diff']=dt.groupby('patient_ID')['diff'].diff().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```py
>> dt[['patient_ID', 'year', 'month', 'diff']]
   patient_ID  year  month  diff
0        4388  2004      8   0.0
1        4388  2007      9  37.0
2        9086  2007      9   0.0
3        9086  2008      6   9.0
4        9086  2011      2  32.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but you did not consider the paitent_id and the groupby for them

Comment: @Jeff - just added it!